wrong ide launches when trying to run file
Im trying to download and run JythonMusic to use alongside my "making music with computers" textbook and am doing something wrong. The download instructions state to download the file and drop it into my applications folder (I'm on a MacBook) which I've done. However, when I click on the folder "JythonMusic" instead of launching the "making music with computers" ide it simply shows me all the python files it contains, and when I click on one of the files it is opened in Xcode. I'm a newbie but Im thinking my python code dosen't have the correct pathname (though I don't know how to check, or change this). Also, I have several versions of python with different ide's for learning and working with python, Thonny, Spider, in addition to Xcode. I'm at the beginning of the learning curve and can't get these pythons to eat what I want them to. Any help would be extremely appreciated...thanks.
I tried to run a program in the Thonny ide and got the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/jythonMusic-master/1. playNote.py", line 4, in 
from music import *        # import music library
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'music'







It is most likely telling you that you do not have the "music" python package installed. This can probably be installed with "pip install music"

when I look at all the packages I've installed music is listed, but I get that error

have you tried running it from the terminal with "python (The path to the file)"

I am one of the developers.  We have created a new version that should take of this problem.  Let us know if this works for you.
See http://JythonMusic.org under the download page.
